# Некорректная работа JObject в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, vknet

пишу бота на библиотеке `VKNet`. Нашёл статью на [Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/441720/), для начала решил просто скопировать имеющийся код оттуда.

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Callback([FromBody] Updates updates)
        {
            switch (updates.Type)
            {
                case "confirmation":
                    return Ok(configuration["Config:Confirmation"]);
                case "message_new":
                {
                    // Десериализация
                    var msg = Message.FromJson(new VkResponse(updates.Object));

                    // Отправим в ответ полученный от пользователя текст
                    vkApi.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams{ 
                        RandomId = new DateTime().Millisecond,
                        PeerId = msg.PeerId.Value,
                        Message = msg.Text
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
```

И класс `Updates`

```
public class Updates
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("object")]
        public JObject Object { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("group_id")]
        public long GroupId { get; set; }
```

И вот я тестирую этот контроллер - шлю, ему JSON, который будет слать сам ВК для проверки работоспособности:

```
{ "type": "confirmation", "object":{ }, "group_id": 205037328 }
```

Всё работает, но стоит мне добавить в `"object"` хоть какое-то поле, сразу выбрасывается ошибка, например:

```
{
   "type":"message_new",
   "object":
   {
       "id": 1
   },
   "group_id":1
}
```

В ответе выбрасывается ошибка

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-9078f59f861dba3d3f1f48511e96b3ef-31f99a6c935d81d0-00",
  "errors": {
    "updates": [
      "The updates field is required."
    ],
    "$.object.id": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $.object.id | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 14."
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Так ASP.NET или ASP.NET Core?

Comment: ASP.NET Core, забыл дописать...

Comment: В таком случае зачем вы используете JSON.NET, если есть System.Text.Json? И почему JObject в модели данных? Это ошибку что возвращает? Ваш сервер или VK?

Comment: Возвращает сервер. VK я пока что не использую, просто через Swagger шлю POST-запросы.
НАсчёт JObject в модели данных, просто переписал код из Хабра, и не работал над его логикой.

Я правильно понимаю, что `JSON.NET` это другое название `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: Правильно понимаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение проблемы. В первую очередь хочу выразить благодарность @aepot за подсказку. Действительно проблемы оказались с `Newtonsoft.JSON` - понятия не имею, почему он не мог десереализовать приходящие данные.

В итоге класс `Updates` переделал следующим образом

```
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

{
    [Serializable]
    public class Updates
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public JsonObject? Object { get; set; }

        public long GroupId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

А `case` с `message_new` сделал следующим образом.

```
case "message_new":
                var peerId = updates.Object["message"]["peer_id"].GetValue<long>();
                vkApi.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
                {
                    RandomId = new DateTime().Millisecond,
                    PeerId = peerId,
                    Message = "Hi!"
                });
                break;
```

В итоге всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @markls, тоже по этой же статье с хабра столкнулся с проблемой использования Core 6. Тоже переделал пока в Updates на JsonObject, а вот потом в case "message_new" можно сделать такой вот костыль:

```
var msg = Message.FromJson(new VkResponse(JObject.Parse(update.Object.ToString())));
```